# Having trouble with .tar.gz extraction

Tags: gzip, extract

I tried to extract .tar.gz file using following command

```
spgt@ubuntu:~$ tar xvf 12.0sp1_232_quartus_free_linux.tar.gz
```

but this is what I see after I press return

```
tar: 12.0sp1_232_quartus_free_linux.tar.gz:  

Cannot open: No such file or directory 

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you in the same folder as your tar file?

Comment: No I am not! should I be? :D well that make sense:D

Comment: Yes, you should. Or, you can specify an absolute path. I don;t generally upvote trivial answers, but this looks right.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
tar -xzvf 12.0sp1_232_quartus_free_linux.tar.gz
```

Comment: Actually, for these options, the `-` is optional. And `z` doesn't have to be given explicitly--when it's a `.tar.gz` archive extracted with `x`, it will automatically behave as if `z` was passed. It turns out the problem was that [the archive was located somewhere else](http://askubuntu.com/a/171462/22949).